# Python2.7: ssh.exec_command works on Ubuntu not on FreeBSD

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ssh, strace

I'm creating an `SSH Channel` to a remote host using `paramiko`.  However, when I try to execute any command using the `ssh_object.exec_command`, the command doesn't seem to get executed on **FreeBSD boxes, but it works on Ubuntu boxes**. Is there any permission issue or prerequisite I need to check for in the remote machines?

This function creates my `ssh` handler:

```
def ssh_connect(ip,user,pwd):
    '''
    This function will make an ssh connection to the ip using the credentials passed and return the handler
    Args:
        ip: IP Address of the box into which ssh has to be done
        user: User name of the box to which ssh has to be done
        pass: password of the box to which ssh has to be done
    Returns:
        An ssh handler
    '''
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, username=user, password=pwd)  
    return ssh
```

And this is where I'm using the handler:

```
ssh_obj = ssh_connect(ip, username, password)
folder = "/var/xyz/images/" + build_number
command = "mkdir " + folder
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh_obj.exec_command(command)
```

When I go to the remote machine, the folder has not got created. Similarly, I tried reading the output of an `ls` command as well. No response arrives when I do `ssh_stdout.read()`.

There's not response when I run `ssh_stderr.read()` either.

The `strace` of the process ID is stuck here:

```
root@ubuntu:~# strace -p 2368
Process 2368 attached
futex(0xef1e20, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you execute the same commands with the command-line ssh utility?

Comment: Yes, I am able to.

Comment: By default, SSH in FreeBSD is configured not to allow login using password, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: But i'm able to `ssh` into the `FreeBSD` box from the same box where I'm running the script. The `ssh` part is successful, it's only the command execution that fails.

Comment: Are you using a password or a public key?

Comment: I'm using a username password combination.